# Integrar Programa comercial con aplicación GPLv3

Tags: mysql, licencias, gpl

Tengo una duda con respecto a la licencia GPLv3.
Tengo una Aplicación de Punto de venta y emisión de boleta electrónica en .NET y desarrollada en Visual Studio 2010 la cual quiero conectar con un tpv open source. Esta conexión seria unicamente vía MySQL de donde extraería la información de vales emitidos los que integraría a mi software para finalmente convertirlos en una boleta.
¿Es esto posible bajo los términos de la licencia?

Answer (score 1):

Si estás entregando el TPV GPLv3 como parte de tu software o incluso si estás enlazando estática o dinámicamente (*static linking* o *dynamic linking*) con dicho TPV la respuesta es **no**. De la FAQ de la GPL:

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.es.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

> Usted no puede incorporar programas cubiertos por la GPL a un sistema privativo. El objetivo de la GPL consiste en garantizar a todo el mundo la libertad de copiar, redistribuir, examinar y modificar el programa. Si le estuviera permitido incorporar software cubierto por la GPL a un sistema privativo, la consecuencia sería que el software cubierto por la GPL se convertiría también en software privativo.

Sin embargo, si *no* estás distribuyendo junto con tu programa el TPV, en general la respuesta es **sí**, pero *no soy tu abogado* y deberías consultar tu caso.

Por otra parte, el lenguaje en el que esté desarrollado (.NET) y el entorno utilizados (Visual Studio 2010) **no influyen** en este ni en ningún caso.

Comment: Estimado A que te refieres puntualmente con Distribuir junto con mi programa ¿? Puntualmente a cobrar por el ?

Comment: No, no tiene nada que ver con cobrar. Con "distribuir" me refiero a "entregar a tu cliente". Para uso interno no tienes por qué preocuparte de la licencia http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.es.html#InternalDistribution